# Check if query was successful in sqlite for Android

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

In order to insert data into a sqlite table named mytable in android I use query:

```
db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('','"+name+"',NOW());");
```

I want to check whether this query was successfully inserted into the table or not.
In php (with mysql) you could easily do

```
if($result) 
    echo 'success';
else        
    echo 'not inserted';
```

But what is the equivalent code in android (with sqlite) **to check whether the query has been successfully 
executed without any error**?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the documentation [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)) throws an [SQLException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/SQLException.html) so I think your best bet is to surround your execSQL call with a try catch. You can then deal with whatever errors occurs in the catch. So something like this is what you want

```
try {
  db.execSQL("INSERT INTO MYTABLE VALUES('','"+name+"',NOW());");
} catch (SQLException e) {
  ...deal with error
}
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea, I could use return in catch statement to stop further execution of program..thanks.

Comment: @paul - any time! glad I could help :)